# PyInstaller + Tkinter, distribution not found

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've looked around as much as I can on this over the last 2 days and have not found this error message anywhere else. I am using a fresh Python 3.10.4 installation, a fresh virtualenv, and a fresh PyInstaller 5.0 installation. This is on Windows 10.

When packaging my program for distribution, I get the following warnings (but it still continues packaging):

```
718 WARNING: Unable to copy metadata for tkinter: The 'tkinter' distribution was not found and is required by the application

1078 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...

9110 WARNING: Unable to determine requirements for tkinter: The 'tkinter' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I'm not sure why it's not able to find tkinter, given that it is now included with Python. For reference, my PyInstaller command is as follows:

`pyinstaller --onedir --noconsole --key=ThisIsAKey --hidden-import=tkinter --collect-all=tkinter myscript.py`

The program does finish packaging and I can run the .exe file. The GUI I built even comes up. However, the filedialog window does not show up on startup as it should, and two of my three buttons do not function at all.

Comment: I would recommend opening an issue on the PyInstaller GitHub repository. We'll be able to help you more there.

Comment: @Legorooj I've opened a bug issue that has since been closed due to the `--collect-all=tkinter` flag, but still having the same issues with the buttons, filedialog, and the canvas not updating.

Comment: I'm watching the issue :P